# Problems running mysql on MAMP

Tags: php, mysql, ruby-on-rails, rubygems, mamp

I am trying to get the MySQL server on MAMP to run, but to no avail.

It was working fine, but I stopped using MAMP when I started using Ruby on Rails. Now I want to work on some older PHP projects that live in my MAMP install and I can't fire them up. Most frustrating.

I suspect it is related to the MySQL gem installed with RoR, but I am unsure as to how I can check or how I would fix the conflict.

My question, essentially, is "how can I start my mySql server?"

Os: 10.7.4
MAMP V: 1.8.4

I have check the logs:

Output of `tail mysql_error_log.err -n 100`:

```
==> mysql_error_log.err <==
120715 12:11:41 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port: Address already in use
120715 12:11:41 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
120715 12:11:41 [ERROR] Aborting

120715 12:11:41  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
120715 12:11:42  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 0 44233
120715 12:11:42 [Warning] Forcing shutdown of 2 plugins
120715 12:11:42 [Note] /Applications/MAMP/Library/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete

120715 12:11:42 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.pid ended
```

**Update**

I have tried to edit the my.cnf of the running instances, as suggested. I dod this my running `locate my.cnf` to find the files.

that returned two results, one which was in MAMP PRO (which I am not using) and another (based in Macports). I chose to edit [lines 15 and 34 of the Macports file.](http://pastebin.com/dNSCrnS6). I then restarted the machine.

It appears I am getting the same error:

```
==> mysql_error_log.err <==
120715 13:37:26 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port: Address already in use
120715 13:37:26 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
120715 13:37:26 [ERROR] Aborting

120715 13:37:26  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
120715 13:37:27  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 0 44233
120715 13:37:27 [Warning] Forcing shutdown of 2 plugins
120715 13:37:27 [Note] /Applications/MAMP/Library/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete

120715 13:37:27 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.pid ended
```

Answer (score 1):

> 120715 12:11:41 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port: Address already in use
>
> 120715 12:11:41 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?

You already have MySQL or some other program using the port 3306. You can either terminate the existing program or use a different port.

The port can be changed in the MySQL configuration file `my.cnf`.

Comment: I have edited the question to explain where I am after following this advice. See after the Update header. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on Mac and I installed MySql separate of MAMP, at some point. This version of MySql was blocking MAMP's MySql server.

Open up System Preferences and if you see a MySQL icon on the bottom row, open it up. Here it told me that I had a MySQL server instance running. Stop the server and uncheck "Automatically Start MySQL Server on Startup"

Hope this helps someone!